# How to get the latest mail from hotmail account using TcpClient and SslStream

Tags: c#, windows, tcpclient, hotmail, sslstream

I have created a windows test app in which i am connecting to my hotmail account and checking the unread mails there.Currently through my app ,i m getting the last mail from my hotmail account.

How can i get the latest mail and whether is it possible to get the subject and body of the latest mail using SSLStream object.

I am posting my code here.Please help me with this one.Any proper help will be appreciated.The place where it is written that "to get the first mail",i am only getting the total bytes of the first mail.Please help me to get the first email subject and body.

```
        TcpClient mail = new TcpClient();
        SslStream sslStream;
        int bytes = -1;
        mail.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);
        sslStream = new SslStream(mail.GetStream());
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop3.live.com");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        // Read the stream to make sure we are connected
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
        MessageBox.Show(message);

        //Send the users login details
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USER user_name\r\n"));
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string message1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
        MessageBox.Show(message1);

        //Send the password                        
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PASS password\r\n"));
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
        MessageBox.Show(message2);

        // Get the first email 
        sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RETR 1\r\n"));
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string message4 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
        MessageBox.Show(message4);

        string str = string.Empty;
        string strTemp = string.Empty;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslStream); 
        while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            // find the . character in line
            if (strTemp == ".")
            {
                break;

            }
            if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
            {
                break;

            }
            str += strTemp;

        }
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
```

With some modifications in the code i am able to access the hotmail account.But with the same code when i try to access the AOl account.I am getting IO exception.Can anyone help me to how to connect to AOL mail sysytem using this code.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to implement the pop protocol to get email for pop server; in your case hotmail. You will find good article about opening mails from pop3 servers like hotmail/gmail over [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261607/Receiving-Mail-through-the-POP3-Protocol-MIME-Pars)

Comment: Can u elaborate a more,i dont have that much knowledge with pop please

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can test your hotmail mail retrieval with sample here and understand how to accomplish it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261607/Receiving-Mail-through-the-POP3-Protocol-MIME-Pars

Comment: Can i download the class library and use that with my project.Is it available there for download.Thanks for helping me .Please reply to this one too

Comment: Find "Download source" or "Download demo" on give page

Comment: I copied the DLL named "pop3lib.dll" and will try to check using the DLL

Comment: Its showing the error that an existing connection was forcibly closed by the host.

Comment: Cant i get the email content using the sslstream?

Comment: I am using the same credentials using tcp client and its working

Comment: Its showing the error that an existing connection was forcibly closed by the host

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. Check your inputs and port access as I have tested my email and it did not give me any error.

Comment: FOr hotmail its port 995 right,i checked with this Pop3Lib.Client myPop3 = new Pop3Lib.Client
   ("pop.gmail.com", "username@gmail.com", "password", 995);,after the executionof this line i m getting the exception

Comment: I just added the dll and then created the object of pop3lib.client .

Comment: The server name i m using is "pop3.live.com".Is this causing the issue?

Comment: If you are using gmail then use pop.gmail.com and all the credentials should be of gmail

Comment: No i m not using gmail,i am doing with hotmail and i also want for AOL